Adaptive Card Conversation Limit Issue in Teams via Bot Framework Connector
We are sending an adaptive card containing text blocks, column sets, and action sets via the bot framework. We are sending the adaptive card to the Teams channel. Below is an example of such an adaptive card.

In some cases, we wanted to send up to 50 conversations, adding them as a column set in the adaptive card, and sending it to the Teams channel using the bot framework connector client.
Also, we restrict the conversation count to 20900 in the code, we can still add over 30 conversations to the adaptive card, but Teams only displays 15 to 20 conversations once its send to the teams' channel.
Is there a character limit for sending adaptive cards via the bot connector client?

Yes, there is a limitation according to the documentation for MS Teams -> 28 KB ( MS Team Limitations  ) is an approximate limit because it includes the message itself (text, image links, etc.), @-mentions, number of connectors, and reactions.

The overall limitation for bot messages is 40 KB, but in Teams, this may change as mentioned above. We also faced the same issue and had to limit the content. Remember, if you push more information, readability will suffer, so try to reduce the information to meet visual needs.
Bot Message Limit


But here we are not getting any exception, but it automatically reduces the number of messages which they include in the adaptive card. In case we have added 50 messages and once its received the receiver side it might be only 15 messages

@Aiswarya Which card version are you using? I am not sure if the latest version of the card has a feature like trimming the excess contents. If it extends more than 28 KB, then it will definitely break. I have seen different behaviors in the card. For E.g In the dropdown list, if you push more than 28 KB, it will default to showing a blank drop down list. At the card level, if it shows a message, then it will throw an exception mentioned above. Probably in your card, there is also something like a 28 KB issue, and it behaves in different ways.
